# Error message "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this code:

```
string cs = "Data Source=IS020114\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=gcOnesti;Integrated Security=True";

    string select = "SELECT p.cod AS Numar, p.data AS Data, c.nume AS Furnizor, d.nume AS DocFurnizor, p.doc_cod AS NrDocFurnizor, p.validat AS Validat, p.facturat AS Contat, g.nume AS Gestiune FROM primar p INNER JOIN cf c ON p.part1=c.cf_id INNER JOIN gestiuni g ON p.part2 = g.gest_id INNER JOIN documente d ON p.doc_id = d.doc_id WHERE (p.tip = '2') ORDER BY p.Data";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                col.HeaderText = "Selecteaza";
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
                col.Width = 65;
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[6].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[8].ReadOnly = true;
            }
 private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        txtNumar.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmbValidat.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        cmbContat.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to get the values from `DataGridView` and see them on my ToolStrip textbox and comboboxes but when I click on some other column except column6 or column7, I get this error. Could anyone help me understand what am I missing? Thanks

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: You need to check the selected row index is valid, sometimes its -1 this especially happens if you click on the header

Comment: arrays start at index 0 -> `dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;` you forgot and index 8 is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your SQL-Statement, you call the Columns wrong. I think it should be following code, because arrays start at index `0` and index `8` will throw the `outOfRangeException` because the array has a length of only 8 from 0 - 7:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[6].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;
```

And further below you should use for Numar, Validat and Contat different indexes, otherwise you will have wrong values:

```
txtNumar.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
cmbValidat.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
cmbContat.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: @Thanks, it worked. I have another problem now. After I filter through  that textbox and I delete the value I searched for, the index for `cmbValidat.Text` is changed automatically to the last one. What's the problem?

Comment: @cdrrrrrr can you ask this in a new question? it's really hard to say without code

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that you're trying to access a collection of item by index and your index is invalid. Then you will get this error.

So advised you to check whether you have valid index for `Columns` before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[6].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;
```

start index from Zero, as mention in sql statement you have only 8 columns which start from 0 to 7.  so dataGridView1.Columns[8].ReadOnly = true; will rise exception "Index was out of range".